# Install Ubuntu (18.04) with option to add new OS in future - can't define 'device from boot loader installation'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I need to install Ubuntu on new device - (not as virtual machine) 
and I want to define a partition that will be a static partition that will contain the device boot loader.

I created a first partition that I defined as ext4 and the mount point of /boot.
(/dev/sda1)

Now, I'm trying to change the 'device from boot loader installation' to be this  partition but I have only the option of the /dev/sda (that is all the disk) 
or /dev/sda3 (that is the partition that I defined to contain the Ubuntu)

When I will install other kind of Linux OS I want to still run the loader from the /dev/sda1   -   and I don't know how to continue  my installation now.

Any help please.

Comment: How does sda1 differ from sda3? If you, for some reason, what the bootloader installed to a partition, sda3 should suit just as well.

Comment: Do you install in UEFI-mode or in legacy-mode?